# How to select external components for a buck converter?

Tags: pwm, buck, step-down

I design a simple circuit activates fan when processor heats up and then control rotation speed.  The fan has a brushless motor with an internal motor controller. So I got the idea to create a buck-mode step-down voltage convertor like this:
[image]

[image]

**Is my calculation correct?** 
**Should I use Low ESR capacitors for the buck converter?**

FAN: Sunon MF50100V1-1000U-A99, DC 5V, Imax 180mA@5V, Vapo-Bearing™ technology

Comment: Most likely the fan controller starts to draw more current when you give it less voltage. I suggest to change the fan to a 12V fan that already has a PWM input so you can remove most, if not all components drawn in your circuit.

Comment: Actually fan impedance steady state is fairly resistive increasing current with voltage, but surges with acceleration. Above stall... but intermodulation current is a problem

Comment: Consider a design for VCCC for variable current with low motor ripple current.